# Primefaces generated PDF from iText is showing blank in object component

Tags: java, jsf, pdf, primefaces, outputstream

I need your assistant in showing the content of a PDF document in an `object` component.Currently the PDF is shown as blank.

The bean code is:

```
    public void  CreatePDF() throws IOException {
      try{
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out);
        doc.open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("First PDF"));
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
        table.addCell(cell);
        doc.add(table);
        doc.close();
        out.close();

        InputStream in =new ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream)out).toByteArray());

                    streamedContent = new DefaultStreamedContent(in, "application/pdf");

                Map<String, Object> session = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
                byte[] b = (byte[]) session.get("reportBytes");
                if (b != null) {
                    streamedContent = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(b), "application/pdf");
                }         
      }
        catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

And the jsf code:

```
<p:commandButton value="Show PDF"  actionListener="#{pdf.CreatePDF}"  icon="ui-icon-disk" update=":request:testpdf" />

<p:media id="testpdf" value="#{pdf.streamedContent}" width="190" height="250" player="pdf"/>
```

Now I got the below error:

> ]] Root cause of ServletException. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/el/ValueReference   at
>   org.primefaces.el.InterceptingResolver.getValue(InterceptingResolver.java:51)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.el.ValueExpressionAnalyzer.intercept(ValueExpressionAnalyzer.java:69)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.el.ValueExpressionAnalyzer.getExpression(ValueExpressionAnalyzer.java:45)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.util.DynamicResourceBuilder.build(DynamicResourceBuilder.java:49)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.media.MediaRenderer.getMediaSrc(MediaRenderer.java:125)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.media.MediaRenderer.encodeEnd(MediaRenderer.java:42)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:884)

Comment: The `<object data>` must represent an URL (exactly the one as you'd enter in browser's address bar in order to manually download the PDF). Have you looked at `<p:media>`?

Comment: That class is new since EL 2.2 (Java EE 6). Are you running on a Java EE 6 compatible server or newer? If so, are you sure webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` does not contain JAR files of an older versioned EL library?

Comment: @BalusC we are having weblogic server the latest one. Yes they are there.

Comment: `/WEB-INF/lib` should not contain any libraries which are already provided by server itself, such as Java EE, JSF, EL, Servlet, etc.

Comment: @BalusC I will remove and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iText WAR file is kept under the /lib folder and it has worked fine. The compatible version is iText 2.1.7 please refer to the Dependencies in the documentation